# Need to Hide the edge of the card but transparent to see the background?

Tags: css, hide

[image: Need to Hide the edge of the card but transparent to see the background?]

I have this css issue, where the design cuts off this edge, and should show the background.  I am currently absolute positioning a corner over top of the blue edge to hide it.

But the client wants to change the background from time to time, so then it will not look right.  Is there any way of now allowing the corner to show thru but still have the transparency to see any background?

You can see a larger view of it here:
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0de37k32e

EDIT:
I can't just put a background image on this corner, because it is a dynamic page that is pulling these 'cards' which are all the same set dimensions.

Comment: What is keeping you from having the actual card itself be a png to allow for transparency of that edge?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a transparent png for the actual design area there?

Comment: I am talking about the actual card design itself. The only other way is to add something there like you have.

Answer (score 0):

The "social buzz" button area should be a `div` with a background image that contains the angle, which on the image is just a transparent area. That's all there is to it.